# NextJS Hydration error after importing font

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to use a font in my project. I've imported the font as such:

```
import { Lexend } from 'next/font/google';

const lexend = Lexend({ subsets: ["latin"] });
```

And implemented it in my component as:

```
const SplashPage = () => {
...

return (
<html lang="en" className={lexend.className}>
<div>
...
</div>
</html>
);
};
```

But I'm getting a hydration error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

My question is twofold:

1. How can I fix it?
2. How am I *supposed* to import fonts into my project if not this way?

Thank you!

Comment: it is simply ui error means you are not following the rules to apply... just like not to use <HTML> tag

Comment: @NaveenNizam how would you add a font to a NextJS project then?

Comment: don't use `html` tag is only allow in `root layout` not `page layout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div lang="en">
 <div className={lexend.className}>
 <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24" >

   <p > Get started by editing &nbsp;</p>
 
 </main>
 </div>
 </div>
```

**You can Check the link also** https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/next-font-n47k96?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A1%2C1